# which is significant way to write < form method ="post" or method="POST" />

Tags: php, forms, post

this is a very normal question, but i think i should clear my confusion.
 in php form we usually write

```
<form method="POST" .../>
```

as we retrive data via `$_POST[''];`
so if i write

```
<form method="post" .../>
```

then can we retrieve data via `$_post[''];`

i just want to know which is better and suggested way to write method value..**"post"** or **"POST"**

thanks

Comment: there is NO RELATION between **html** atribute and PHP array.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: yes, there is, the only thing that is not related is whether the characters are uppercase or lowercase :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no difference at all. It is purely a question of style. I personally prefer to use all lower case. It's easier to type and makes it easier to convert to XHTML, which requires lower case, should you ever choose to convert. [This faq entry](http://www.htmlhelp.com/faq/html/design.html#tag-case) covers lower case vs upper case in a bit more detail. Quoting:

> In HTML, element and attribute names
>   in tags are case insensitive, so it
>   doesn't matter. The choice is just a
>   matter of style and personal
>   preference. (You may have noticed that
>   this FAQ is not absolutely consistent
>   in capitalization.) Many people prefer
>   upper case, which makes the tags
>   "stand out" more amongst the text, and
>   makes it easier to find element or
>   attribute names using an editor's
>   search function. Others prefer lower
>   case, which makes the tags "stand out"
>   less amongst the text, and which is
>   required by XHTML.
>
> Note that some attribute values are
>   case sensitive. For example, `<OL
>   TYPE="A">` and `<ol type="A">` are the
>   same, but `<ol type="a">` is different
>   from either of them. (For clearer
>   communication, it's worth getting the
>   terminology right. In this example, `OL`
>   is the element, `TYPE` is the attribute
>   name, and A or a is the attribute
>   value. The tag is `<OL TYPE="A">`.)
>
> Entity names like `&nbsp;` are sometimes
>   incorrectly referred to as tags. They
>   are all case sensitive. For example,
>   `&Eacute;` and `&eacute;` are two
>   different and valid entities, and
>   while `&nbsp;` is a valid entity, `&NBSP`;
>   is invalid.
>
> Note that XHTML requires all element
>   and attribute names to be in lower
>   case.

Note that `$_POST` must be uppercase, but this has no relation to case used in the HTML.

Comment: Hum, your answer is mostly about how "element and attribute names" are case insensitive in HTML and case sensitive and all lower case in XHTML. But in this case "POST" or "post" is actually the "method" attribute's VALUE ! And, "some attribute values are case sensitive"...

Comment: -1; as @PierreHenry correctly notes, nothing in the block you've quoted is actually relevant to the claim that the `method` attribute's *value* is case-insensitive in HTML 5, nor the claim that it must be lowercase in XHTML.

Answer (score 8):

In HTML, the value of the `method` attribute is case insensitive.

In XHTML, the value is case sensitive and **must** be lower case.

In PHP, the superglobal will always be `$_POST` and never `$_post`.

Comment: The PHP manual would beg to differ: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: Oh, sorry, I removed the comment before I saw your response. For those interested, I said `$_POST` was not a superglobal. I was confused though and was referring to `$HTTP_POST_VARS`. Of course, you are right, David :).

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any difference with `POST` or `post` at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_form_method.asp). However, since HTML5 will introduce all-small-caps-notation (something already present in XHTML), I would stick to small caps.

Comment: w3schools is not a good place to find reliable web. Members of the W3C have asked W3Schools to explicitly disavow any connection, but they have refused to do so.

Comment: I have since stopped using W3Schools for the same reasons. I now read the actual definitions of W3 to look stuff up.

Answer (score 0):

PHP `$_POST` is a built-in function. It's case-sensitive. `$_post` will never work.
In HTML, you can use whatever you wish, as it's case-insensitive.

Answer (score -1):

$_POST is what I've seen always being used in tandem with method="POST".
Anything other than this convention in php will error out. HTML doesn't care since its case-insensitive.

Answer (score -1):

Umh... you will only be able to receive the `post`ed vars in PHP with `$_POST` - and not with `$_post`. No matter if you write `<form method="POST">` or `<form method="post">`.
That is a so called `superglobal array`.

Usually I write every tag and attribute small because it is standard...